# Create Component Dynamically with parameters

Tags: angular, frontend, angular6

I have a component which is dynamically created with ComponentFactoryResolver

```
this.container.clear();
let factory  = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(DynamicComponent);
this.componentRef = this.container.createComponent(factory);

template: '...<child-component [param1]="param1"></child-component>...';
```

The problem is DynamicComponent's template has child component and input bindings. Is there a way to pass parameters to child component when creating the component dynamically?

Comment: Were you able to find an answer to this?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the easiest way to achieve it is:

```
this.componentRef.instance.param1 = param1;
```

But pay attention, this solution is prone to errors. If param1 change over time, you can get

> **EXCEPTION**: Expression has changed after it was checked.

which is not easy to debug.

You could want to use a dependency injection solution, as explained [in this tutorial](https://netbasal.com/create-advanced-components-in-angular-e0655df5dde6).

Comment: Already tried this one and got expression has changed after it was checked error.

Comment: Did you follow the dependency injection tutorial that I linked?

Answer (score 7):

Yes like this:

```js
const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(LoginComponent);
const component: ComponentRef<LoginComponent> = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(factory);
component.instance.user = "prop 1";
component.instance.input2 = "prop 2";
```

Comment: Already tried this one and got expression has changed after it was checked error.

Comment: Try to add this constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef){} Then after you assign the values, use this.cd.detectChanges();

Comment: what is `this.viewContainerRef`

Comment: @Nehal Jaisalmeria `this.viewContainerRef` comes from having something like `<ng-template #viewContainerRef></ng-template>` in the template, which is where the components can be dynamically managed, and then picked up in the components code as something like `@ViewChild("viewContainerRef", { read: ViewContainerRef }) viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef;`