# How to attach angular input to dynamic angular web element

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, web-component

We are trying to pass inputs to an angular web component.
To make system robust,
from api we will get two values

1. Script URL
2. Selector name ( below example `component` we are getting from db as well )

So we are able to add script dynamically and then added selector name by using createElement of renderer2. But now we are stuck as we want to pass inputs to that component like

```
<component [data]="'Hello'"></component>
```

so question is how we can add angular input tags in element which is added in DOM by using

```
renderer.createElement
```

Is it possible to pass or should change logic to add element ?
Main point is both javascript location and selector is dynamic.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at the docs, there are `setAttribute` / `setProperty` methods: https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2

Comment: Oh, ok, from another answer I'm not quite sure if property binding is actually possible with this.

Answer (score 0):

You should create your component via `ComponentFactory` like here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50429222/7255496) and set component inputs manually.

Comment: In my situation we dont have component class or anything as its dynamically loaded from third party. So we can't have instace of component

Answer (score 0):

According to this link : https://angular.io/guide/elements#typings-for-custom-elements

I think you can just specify element.InputName = InputValue;

So In your case it should be

```
const comp = document.createElement('component');
comp.data = 'hello';
```